# Find development language(Swift / ObjC) in iOS App programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have a static framework developed in Objective C.
Is there any way to find in which programming language (Swift or Objective-C) developer is developing the app?

I want this because I want to add some features and also to migrate my framework to Swift.

Comment: Need more context.  If you have an ipa, you can check for the presence of the Swift runtime.  That will tell you the app contains Swift code.  To determine ObjC usage, you'll need to check the binary itself for tell-tale symbols.

Comment: The language being used to develop an app has no impact on the language you use to develop a framework.  At the worst, you'll have to provide ObjC-compatible APIs, at least as an option.  (e.g. no Swift structs)